# Kibana Discover UI doesn't recognize newly added indexes in an Alias

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I create monthly indexes from Java Code (using Elastic HL Rest Client) and they have an alias name.
So eg, the index names are of the format **elk-gps-kafka-MMYYYY** and the alias name is **elk-gps-kafka-store**
I have created an index pattern for the alias in Management section of Kibana in august 2020.
So if I search a data using _id field for a data present in July 2020 index, it shows on the discovery UI but if I search using an _id which is present in October 2020 index, it doesn't show on the discovery UI.

However I am able to retrieve this same record present in October 2020 index using _id through query on both index as well as alias.

```
GET /elk-gps-kafka-102020/_search/
{
        "query": { 
        "bool": {
         "filter": {
                "term": {
                   "_id": "GKDVQHUBntLICdSPemNC"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /elk-gps-kafka-store/_search/
{
        "query": { 
        "bool": {
         "filter": {
                "term": {
                   "_id": "GKDVQHUBntLICdSPemNC"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm Using Elastic 6.6
So the issue is basically index pattern doesn't recognize newly added indexes to the alias.

@Val,
Running GET _cat/aliases/elk-gps-kafka-store, shows the data for elk-gps-kafka-102020 index and can query the _id from console but not from discovery UI.

```
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-092020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-112020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-012019 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-082020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-122020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-062020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-102020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-072020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-012020 - - -
elk-gps-kafka-store elk-gps-kafka-052020 - - -
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/aliases/elk-gps-kafka-store`? and how does your index pattern look like ?

Comment: @Val, edited the quetion to answer your query. Already checked this.

Comment: Thanks, what about my second question?

Comment: @Val, Index Pattern I have currently given elk-gps-kafka-store*

Comment: Also, how does your Discover time picker look like? Are you sure it includes the timestamps of the monthly index you're looking into?

Comment: @Val, Got the issue, indeep a very stupid one, I renamed the column and used the old one for the datetime picker. Now made them same and it worked. Feeling stupid now. Thanks so much

Comment: No need to, sometimes a second pair of eyes can come in helpful. Glad you figured it out!